# Are NDBs and VORs dying as a navigational method?

Tags: navigation, flight-instruments, gnss, vor, radio-navigation

I am new to aviation, so bear with me on this question:

I have read in multiple places that the VOR/NDB navigational aids are dying out to GPS. Is this true? Are more modern aircraft being built with glass, digital instrument readouts that capitalize on GPS services instead of the traditional vacuum tube ADF and VOR Indicators?

Comment: "traditional vacuum tube ADF and VOR Indicators"  Tubes?  Pretty sure there are no vacuum tubes in the indicators.  Tubes wouldn't do well in the vibration environment of an airplane.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, without a shadow of a doubt. Many airports now publish GNSS (Generic term for all types of satellite navigation) approaches, completly negating the need for those aids even during complex, critical phases such as approach and landing and take off and departure.

Modern GNSS systems are capable of utilising synthetic VORs where even when doing something such as flying a particular radial, the aircraft actually uses it's GNSS data to do so.

And, if you needed outright evidence, how about this quote from the UK National Air Navigation provider (NATS):

> Commercial aviation – which has always funded the upkeep of the VOR beacons – now almost exclusively relies on the use of satellite navigation (read last week’s post on EGNOS for an example), making the majority of beacons an expensive and unnecessary financial burden. As such by 2020 we will be reducing their number from 44 down to 19.

Source: https://nats.aero/blog/2015/05/has-gps-killed-off-the-vor/

Comment: I'd suppose it would help cut down on expensive infrastructure as well. Reduce the number of giant VHF radio structures and NDB antennae helps keep $$ low......

Comment: @Jon Absolutely, see my edit :)

Comment: The thing that terrifies me, is the satellites could become a prime target for an enemy/terrorist org. What would happen if all satellite-driven services died due to an attack? Are there alternative navigational methods in that worst-case scenario?

Comment: @Jon I think that'd be a good candidate for another question if it hasn't been asked already. Suffice to say, yes - if nothing else, most modern aircraft are equipped with Internal Navigation Systems allowing navigation with no outside help at all

Comment: Ok. There actually already is a question for that. ATC for controlled airspace, and at wost-case, an old-fashioned magnetic compass, aviation map, and pen. :)  Also VFR flight using literal landmarks.

Comment: @Jon If there is terrorist activity that is capable of knocking out enough navigation satellites to render GPS useless, the word "terrorist" has to get replaced with "well funded state actor."  Also, when a well funded state actor decides to take out navigation satellites, that's a great time to be on the ground, at a pub... or maybe a basement. Basements are nice safe places =)

Comment: @CortAmmon Never underestimate the power of screwups. In 2016, the Air Force accidentally [broke the time signal](https://tf.nist.gov/general/pdf/2886.pdf) of GPS for 12 hours when they triggered a bug decommissioning a satellite, then ran into another bug that prevented them from fixing it until the end of the day. Though it didn't affect navigation, it [degraded](http://www.chronos.co.uk/files/pdfs/pres/2017/Impact_of_GPS_UTC_Anomaly_Event_of_January_2016_on_the_Global_Timing_Community.pdf) landline, wireless and broadcast radio services.

Comment: But what about NDBs? Using a NDB gives you information about your bearing (with respect to the NDB). GNSS can give you only information about your position; not bearing.

Comment: @Curd What about them? If you know your absolute position, and the GPS device knows the absolute position of the other aids (NDB, VOR, Towns, Waypoints etc) the it can tell you anything you like - your relative bearing, your distance etc without ever having to "talk" to them. In other words, they don't even need to physically exist and you'd never know while your GNSS was functioning

Comment: @Dan: example: you want to know what angle is between your baseline and the direction to the NDB. Just knowing your position and the position of the NDB (or anything else) doesn't tell you anything about the direction you are looking.

Comment: @Dan: e.g. you could use a NDB as substitute for a compass (if you know about  where you are and the NDB is far away). You can't do that with just knowing your position.

Comment: @Curd I see what you're saying, but I think it's a bad example as NDB's themselves have already mostly been phased out in favour of VOR's, which give the same data as a GNSS system would. Radio Direction Finding has a lot of issues in real life, and it can't give you a real life bearing without user input or slaving to a Direction Indicator anyway.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is true. This [FAA page](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/techops/navservices/transition_programs/vormon/) has more info.

> The **Very High Frequency Omni-directional Range (VOR) Minimum
> Operational Network (MON)** provides a conventional navigation backup
> service in the event of a loss of Global Positioning System (GPS)
> signal. The MON includes the minimum number of geographically situated
> VORs in the contiguous United States (CONUS) necessary to provide
> coverage at and above 5,000 feet above ground level. Additionally, the
> MON supports International Oceanic Arrival Routes and mission critical
> military use.

From the [Federal Radionavigation Plan](https://rosap.ntl.bts.gov/view/dot/32801) the Gerry references in the comments:

**ILS**

> ILS is the standard precision approach system in the U.S. and abroad.
> FAA operates more than 1,200 ILS systems of which approximately 150
> are CAT II or CAT III systems. In addition, DoD operates approximately
> 160 ILS facilities in the U.S. Non-Federal sponsors operate fewer than
> 200 ILS facilities in the U.S.
>
> As the GPS-based augmentation systems
> (WAAS and GBAS) are integrated into the NAS, and user equipage and
> acceptance grows, the number of CAT I ILSs may be reduced. FAA does
> not anticipate phasing out any CAT II or III ILS systems.
>
> The NAS includes more than 1,300 NDBs. Fewer than 300 are owned by the
> Federal Government; the rest are non-Federal facilities owned
> predominately by state, municipal, and airport authorities.

**NDBs**

> FAA has begun decommissioning stand-alone NDBs as users equip with
> GPS. NDBs used as compass locators, or as other required fixes for ILS
> approaches (e.g., initial approach fix, missed approach holding),
> where no equivalent ground-based means are available, may need to be
> maintained until the underlying ILS is phased out. Some NDBs may also
> need to be maintained to facilitate training and proficiency
> requirements. Most NDBs that define low-frequency airways in Alaska or
> serve international gateways and certain offshore areas like the Gulf
> of Mexico will be retained.

Comment: For the rest of the story, read the [Federal Radionavigation Plan](https://www.transportation.gov/pnt/radionavigation-systems-planning).

Comment: @Gerry Interesting document. I’ll have to read it in detail later. One thing that I did not know is that GPS signals are used by spacecraft.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of VORs, maybe as a primary means of navigation it is dying out, but I honestly do not see them being phased out completely within the next decade or so. Most ANSPs prefer keeping them as a secondary means of navigation given that GNSS still relies on GPS developed by the US military.

As for NDBs, I think I've seen only one or two that are still in existence, so yeah they're definitely out.